# Namespace, Trait, and Use in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, traits

I have been trying to use and understand namespace and traits but getting this error:

> "Trait a\b\Train not found" when I run example.php
>
> "Trait a\b\Train not found" when I run Bayes.php

Just confused how it works and why getting error.
Here my code:
(these files store in the same folder)

```
//example.php
use a\classification;
include_once 'Bayes.php';

$classifier = new Bayes();
$classifier -> train($samples, $labels);
$classifier -> predict([something]);

//Bayes.php
namespace a\classification;
use a\b\Predict;
use a\b\Train;
class Bayes { 
  use Train, Predict 
}

//Train.php
namespace a\b;
trait Train{
}

//Predict.php
namespace a\b;
trait Predict{
}
```

I'm sorry for my dumb question, really appreciate for your help :"

Comment: There is no `NaiveBayes` in this code.

Comment: @zerkms sorry updated :')

Comment: You don't load the `Bayes.php` file in `example.php`. php has no idea `Bayes` class is in `Bayes.php`

Comment: @zerkms hmm it didn't load even though I declared `use a\classification`  in `example.php` ?

Comment: `use` does not load anything, that's correct. It just sets the alias (FQN) for the `classification` identifier.

Comment: @zerkms thank you :) I put this `include_once 'bayes.php'` (I think it solved problem number 1) and getting error msg number 2 as I run example.php

Comment: @jill182 did you figure it out?

Comment: @BeetleJuice No, just sure having error in bayes.php :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to include `Train.php` and `Predict.php` inside `Bayes.php`. You're referring to the traits, but how does PHP know about those?

Then, you need to specify a proper namespace when creating a `new Bayes()`. You include the file, but it's in another namespace. The `use` declaration at the top isn't doing much. It lets you create a `new classification\Bayes()` instead of `new a\classification\Bayes()`.

Try something like this instead:

**example.php**

```
<?php
use a\classification\Bayes;
include_once 'Bayes.php';

$classifier = new Bayes();
$samples = "text";
$labels = "text";
$classifier -> train($samples, $labels);
$classifier -> predict(["something"]);
```

**Bayes.php**

```
<?php
namespace a\classification;
require_once 'Train.php';
require_once 'Predict.php';
use a\b\Predict as P;
use a\b\Train as T;
class Bayes
{ 
    use T, P;
}
```

**Train.php**

```
<?php
namespace a\b;
trait Train
{
    public function Train()
    {
        echo "training";
    }
}
```

**Predict.php**

```
<?php
namespace a\b;
trait Predict
{
    function predict()
    {
        echo "predicting";
    }
}
```

Note the use of an alias in Bayes.php: `use a\b\Predict as P;` This is where aliases can be helpful to simplify code. If the alias isn't specified, it just uses the last name without namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation SOO clear for me! :') I've just realized that I must include that files to my code. thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You're running into trouble because you're not requiring the files you need, so PHP doesn't know what you're talking about when you ask it to use some of these classes.

**example.php** requires access to `Bayes.php`

```
use a\classification;
require_once 'Bayes.php';
```

**Bayes.php** requires access to `Train.php` and `Predict.php`

```
namespace a\classification;
require_once 'Train.php';
require_once 'Predict.php';
use a\b\Predict, a\b\Train;

class Bayes { 
  use Train, Predict 
}
```

Note: use `require_once` rather than `include_once` when the external resource is necessary.

Comment: I just figure it now that i have to declared .php file too :") thank you so much